# Is there an alternative to SLI or CrossFire for gaming on multi-GPU setups?

Tags: sli, crossfire

The only options I've found for combining GPUs for better performance when gaming are nVidia's SLI or AMD's CrossFire, but is there another way to combine two GPUs to improve performance in games?

Comment: Not that I know of... These are proprietary techniques by each manufacturer and AMD and Nvidia are the only GPU makers going after the gaming market. Matrox, SIS, Intel, and VIA/S3 have not implemented any kind of multi-GPU networking.

Comment: Why the vote down?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no 3rd party alternative, currently.

Note that Microsoft said DX12 should be able to combine AMD and nV GPUs to even unify VRAM.
See [here](http://www.gamespot.com/articles/directx-12-can-combine-nvidia-and-amd-cards/1100-6425565/) .

In practical cases, it is know for instances where users preferred using a main Radeon card alongside a lesser Gefroce card that they were using purely for vendor-specific physx functionality.

Answer (score 2):

There was one company/patent holder who attempted this as a 3rd party - Lucid Logix. As you can tell, no one hear remembers the day that Hydra Engine came into being. It received mixed-to-poor marks from many who reviewed it. The results from the successful tests and benchmarks speak volumes for systems with two or more identical GPUs. Mixing brands provided a nominal bump, however. For more information, look here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydra_Engine

https://hothardware.com/reviews/lucid-hydra-200-multigpu-performance-revealed?